# How can I set up Composer with perforce

Tags: composer-php, perforce

How do I set up Perforce with Composer so that files such as the vendor folder are not writable by Perforce?

For example the composer lock file.

Comment: What do yo want to achieve?

Comment: to stop perforce overwriting files and composer pulling our repo from perforce when needed

Comment: Whatever perforce does under the hood, why should it overwrite files in `vendor`? Did you put them under version control?

Comment: Use client mappings to specify which files in your workspace are under version control.

Answer (score 1):

Three options (you can do any or all of these):

1. Add these files to your P4IGNORE.  That will stop you from adding them.
2. Remove these files from your client view.  That will stop you from adding them OR syncing them.
3. Remove these files from the protections table (this requires you to be an admin).  That will stop ANYONE from adding them.